# Mapping an object, converting into an array, then convert back to object

Tags: javascript, redux

I have this code that i use in a redux reducer:

```
  case 'REMOVE_FL_EVENT' : 
    return{
      ...state,
      events: Object.keys(state.events).map(group => {
        return state.events[group].filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
      })
    }
```

What happens here is that the state.events is an object, where every key is the name of the group of it's events, the value is an array with the events. What i want to do is when i convert the object into an array with map, if the filter happened convert back to it's original state, where state.events is not an array, but an object, with the original names of the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `map`, you could use `reduce` only, something like:

```
 {
  ...state,
  events: Object.keys(state.events).reduce(
    (obj, event) => ({
      ...obj,
      [group]: state.events[group].filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
    }),
    {}
  )
```

};

#### Update

The `reduce` has the following signature:

`arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])`

So in our script, we are giving an empty object as the initial value for the accumulation.

Comment: Where the second parameter of reduce (event) came into play?

Comment: It's necessary? Why do we need it? I mean, in which situations it gets used?

Comment: @DorLask if we didn't establish an initial value then `reduce` would use the first element in the array as the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map/reduce for this purpose. First map it and then reduce it into an object.

```
case 'REMOVE_FL_EVENT' : 
  return{
    ...state,
    events: Object.keys(state.events).map(group => {
      return { [group]: state.events[group].filter(item => item.id !== action.id) }
    }).reduce((obj, event) => Object.assign(obj, event), {})
  }
```

The output will be an object with keys as groups. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

With standard JS, you can use `reduce` to convert the array back to an obj:

`arr.reduce((acc, o) => Object.assign(acc, o), {})`

Using `ramda.js` you can filter Objects and their nested properties.  https://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter